# React native Receive notification but not show pop-up in android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

AndroidManifest.xml
This is My android manifest file, notifications comes properly but not showing popup like other applications. Application is in foreground sate or background state popup is not showing notifications are show in notification tray only.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pushnotificationexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
<!--        <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.channel_create_default" android:value="true"/>-->
        <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
            android:value="true"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Push Notification Listener

```
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
      navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
    });

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
          setInitialRoute(remoteMessage.data.type); // e.g. "Settings"
        }
        setLoading(false);
      });
```

Above Listener Will Be Handled When Application Is In Background State OR Killed.

But When Application Is In Foreground Use Code Below

```
messaging().onMessage(remoteMessage => {
   PushNotification.localNotification({
     id: "1", ....
     // Configure Local Notification
   })
 }
)
```

[Firebase Referece](https://rnfirebase.io/)

[Firebase PushNotification PayLoad](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)